# Function in pytest file works only with hard coded values

Tags: pytest, assert, fixtures, hardcoded, parametrized-testing

I have the below `test_dss.py` file which is used for pytest:

```
import dataikuapi

import pytest
 

def setup_list():

    client = dataikuapi.DSSClient("{DSS_URL}", "{APY_KEY}")

    client._session.verify = False

    project = client.get_project("{DSS_PROJECT}")

    # Check that there is at least one scenario TEST_XXXXX & that all test scenarios pass

    scenarios = project.list_scenarios()

    scenarios_filter = [obj for obj in scenarios if obj["name"].startswith("TEST")]

    return scenarios_filter

 
def test_check_scenario_exist():

    assert len(setup_list()) > 0, "You need at least one test scenario (name starts with 'TEST_')"

 
@pytest.mark.parametrize("scenario", setup_list())

def test_scenario_run(scenario, params):

    client = dataikuapi.DSSClient(params['host'], params['api'])

    client._session.verify = False

    project = client.get_project(params['project'])

    scenario_id = scenario["id"]

    print("Executing scenario ", scenario["name"])

    scenario_result = project.get_scenario(scenario_id).run_and_wait()

    assert scenario_result.get_details()["scenarioRun"]["result"]["outcome"] == "SUCCESS", "test " + scenario[

    "name"] + " failed"
```

My issue is with `setup_list` function, which able to get only hard coded values for `{DSS_URL}`, `{APY_KEY}`, `{PROJECT}`. I'm not able to use `PARAMS` or other method like in `test_scenario_run`
any idea how I can pass the `PARAMS` also to this function?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are doing, but I assume that you want to access the config values passed via command line in the code used for parametrization. This could be done by parametrizing the test dynamically using `pytest_generate_tests`.

Comment: I want to be able to use the params also in the function `setup_list` but it only works hard coded...

Comment: You cannot use these params in a function, because the function knows nothing about them. As I wrote, you can do this in `pytest_generate_tests`, if you need the function only for the parametrization. Is that correct?

Comment: correct. can you show me example on how it should look on my code?

Comment: Tell me if I understand correctly. I should add to `conftest.py`: `def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc): metafunc.parametrize(host,api,project)` and to  `test_dss.py` this addition to the function: `def setup_list(host,api,project):`

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear for other users which run into the same issue. @MrBeanBremen tell me if it's clear enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters in the `mark.parametrize` marker are read at load time, where the information about the config parameters is not yet available. Therefore you have to parametrize the test at runtime, where you have access to the configuration.

This can be done in `pytest_generate_tests` (which can live in your test module):

```py
@pytest.hookimpl
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "scenario" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        host = metafunc.config.getoption('--host')
        api = metafuc.config.getoption('--api')
        project = metafuc.config.getoption('--project')
        metafunc.parametrize("scenario", setup_list(host, api, project))
```

This implies that your `setup_list` function takes these parameters:

```py
def setup_list(host, api, project):
    client = dataikuapi.DSSClient(host, api)
    client._session.verify = False
    project = client.get_project(project)
    ...
```

And your test just looks like this (without the `parametrize` marker, as the parametrization is now done in `pytest_generate_tests`):

```py
def test_scenario_run(scenario, params):
    scenario_id = scenario["id"]
    ...
```

The parametrization is now done at run-time, so it behaves the same as if you had placed a `parametrize` marker in the test.

And the other test that tests `setup_list` now has also to use the `params` fixture to get the needed arguments:

```py
def test_check_scenario_exist(params):
    assert len(setup_list(params["host"], params["api"], params["project"])) > 0,
 "You need at least ..."
```

Comment: one row above the `def test_scenario_run(scenario):` I have: `@pytest.mark.parametrize("scenario", setup_list())` . I'm using it so I can run in loop on this list which returns from the function `setup_list` with the iterator `scenario`. what I should modify there?

Comment: As I wrote in the answer - you don't need this, as you do the parametrization at run-time. Just remove it, as shown above. Added another note.

Comment: but then I have this line after `scenario_id = scenario["id"]` : `scenario_result = project.get_scenario(scenario_id).run_and_wait()`, and it throws error: `NameError: name 'project' is not defined`

Comment: Ok, if you need the project, you also have to use the `params` fixture - I didn't see this in your question. Edited the answer again... It looks a bit strange that you use the same code in the test and in `setup_list`.

Comment: Looks better (you can edit your answer with that). Now the only issue left is with the len assert test.: `def test_check_scenario_exist():
>       assert len(setup_list()) > 0, "You need at least one test scenario (name starts with 'TEST_')"
E       TypeError: setup_list() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'host', 'api', and 'project'`

Comment: Works like charm :) just edit the last params instead the empty value: `params["project"]`

Comment: @MrBeanBremen regards the success results, currently after running Junit I'm getting these results in jenkins for all the scenarios which passed: `tests_project.run_test_CI.test_scenario_run[scenario0] (from pytest)`, any idea how can I show the instead or in addition the `scenario["name"]`? maybe with that: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/usage.html#record-property

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Maybe you write a separate question that makes this more clear? This will also improve the chance of getting an answer...